# Prove that these polynomials don't all have only real roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose $ a_0, . . . , a_{100}$ are positive reals. Consider the following polynomial for each $ k$
in {0, 1, . . . , 100}:
$$a_{100+k}x
^{100} + 100 a_{99+k}x
^{99}+ a_{98+k}x^{98}+a_{97+k}x^{97} · · · + a_{2+k}x
^2 + a_{1+k}x + a_k$$
where indices are taken modulo $101$, i.e., $a_{100+i} = a_{i−1}$ for any i in {1, 2, . . . , 100}.
Show that it is impossible that each of these $101$ polynomials has all its roots real.

Using Descartes' rule pf sign. It gives no positive roots. But putting $-x$ gives $100$ sign changes. So $100$ negative roots. I don't know no how to prove this in general. Could someone help me?

Comment: instead of 100  try 2;  indices mod 3,  $a_{2+k} x^2 + 2 a_{1+k} x + a_k .$    Call them $a,b,c$   for three polynomials, cyclic, $ax^2 + 2b x + c,  b x^2 + 2c x + a, c x^2 + 2ax + b.$  Discriminants  (divided by 4)  $b^2 - ca, c^2 - ab, a^2 - bc.$   Can all three be positive, or at least nonnegative?  I guess, take $a=b=c=1$  roots are all $-1.$

Comment: try 4,    $a,b,c,d,e$ positive, $a x^4 + 4 b x^3 + c x^2 + dx + e$   and cyclic. This time, if all $a,b,c,d,e$ are $1,$   two real and two complex roots

Comment: @WillJagy . But for 100 it would be difficult because we have methods for quadritic and biquadritic. Csn you prove for 100?

Comment: Vipin, I am investigating. It already seems that this is about the relative size of the coefficients; for example, what happens when the largest coefficient is the first one? Possibly better, what about when the second is the largest?  Worth conituing with degree 4.  General message: contest problems often have a single trick  for solving. Actual mathematics   generally has a few steps and investigation of easy cases/subproblems helps

Comment: @WillJagy yes I agree. Probably you could get there.

Comment: as to the specific problem, with a cyclic permutation we can put the largest  $a_j$ wherever we like. Or, say, the extreme pair giving maximum $a_j / a_{j+1} $  Anyway, errands to do

Comment: @WillJagy do you managed to solve it?

Comment: Hint: Just use Vieta's formulae for the sum and the product of the roots (which, as you correctly stated, can be only negative) and AM-GM.